# Keeps saying invalid domain when trying to add it to my app in app settings

Tags: dns, facebook-apps

When I try to add my domain and website to my app in the basic config for my app it keeps telling me it is and invalid domain, but it should work, it used to...

I try putting it into the "App Domains" and "Site Url" fields but get this error...

"Error
App Domains: illmethods.com is not a valid domain.
Site URL is not a valid URL."

The app name is IllMethods

Comment: What software are you using? Try adding http:// at the front. I tried going to that site. DNS could not find it. Maybe the software is checking to see if the site exists.

Comment: it was supposed to be domain as the tag but it changed it to dns...

It is running on a whm server running centos 6.3 64 bit.

Comment: I have added the http:// to it but you dont add that to the apps domain field, it wont let you, in the site domain you add http:// there, it have added it all properly, it just wont let me do it...

Answer (score 1):

If you asked the `com` authoritative DNS servers, you get these NS records and associated glue (A) records:

```
$ dig +norecurs +noall +auth +answer +additional illmethods.com @a.gtld-servers.net
illmethods.com.     172800  IN  NS  ns1.illmethods.com.
illmethods.com.     172800  IN  NS  ns2.illmethods.com.
ns1.illmethods.com. 172800  IN  A   203.97.122.126
ns2.illmethods.com. 172800  IN  A   125.236.226.87
```

but if you asked `ns1.illmethods.com`, the A record for "ns1.illmethods.com" is different from above:

```
$ dig +norecurs +noall +answer +additional illmethods.com @ns2.illmethods.com
illmethods.com.     14400   IN  A   125.236.226.87
ns1.illmethods.com. 14400   IN  A   125.236.226.87
ns2.illmethods.com. 14400   IN  A   125.236.226.87
```

So "ns1" and "ns2" are essentially pointing to the same IP.

I think the issue is a culmination of a few factors:

- negative caching. If your server was down at some point, Facebook's upstream DNS might have cached the negative response for some time.
- inconsistent A records for name servers specified at the registrar vs. what's in the zone that you host.
- Facebook probably has a very short timeout when it queries the DNS, since ns1 is actually not reachable (at least now from where I am), it will likely timeout before it manages to try the other IP.

So, I suggest that you remove ns1.illmethods.com at your registrar, and then remove the NS record of the same in your zone as well. Then, wait at least an hour (if you want to be doubly sure, wait 24hrs since you've specified 86400 in your SOA minimum field) and try again.

You should also use the dnscheck link that Sean Kinsey gave provided to make sure that your zone is free of errors, because these become hard-to-diagnose errors in the presence of caching and different DNS resolver implementations.

Answer (score 0):

There are no valid NS servers listed for this domain and so Facebook probably can't verify it. Currently it has ns1.illmethods.com and ns2.illmethods.com, but that causes a catch 22 as you need the IP for the NS-servers in order to look up the IP for the NS-servers...

See http://dnscheck.pingdom.com/?domain=illmethods.com for more.

Comment: The server is currently down, I am reinstalling it, the server was up when I was getting the errors